# ASP.NET MVC 3 Model Id using Route Id value

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

**Scenario**
Route: /template/customize/10
Where: 10 = ID of Template()

In the controller the model is created based on the template so that the View's model is actually a Customization() object which actually has an Id of 0 because it's new.

In the view I render @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.Id ) and the resulting value of that hidden input is **10**, though it should be **0** because m is of type Customization.  I've run into this before with MVC 2 and worked around it by not using helper methods.

**Questions**

1. Is there annotation or something I
   can add to the Html Helper method to
   actually render the correct value?
2. Is this a bug (MVC seems to be
   rendering m.Id as the route value
   regardless of what the actual model
   is set to in the controller)?

**Additional code for clarification**

**View**

```
@model Project.Core.Domain.Customization
@using( Html.BeginForm( "save", "customization" ) )
{
    @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.Id )
    @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.Template.Id )
    <button type="submit" id="save" name="save">Save</button>
}
```

**Controller**

```
       public ActionResult Customize( int id )
    {
        var template = Persistence.Data.RetrieveObject<Template>( id );
        var model = new Customization();

        ViewBag.Template = template;
        return ( View( model ) );
    }
```

**Solution**

Changed signature of Action to:

```
public ActionResult Customize( int TemplateId ){ ... }
```

Changed link to action as such:

```
@Html.ActionLink( "customize", "customize", new { TemplateId = template.Id } )
```

I end up with a url that looks like

```
/template/customize?TemplateId=10
```

It's uglier, but I get to keep my view clean with model.Id so this is a win for me.

Comment: Could you please show some code? Controller and View would be helpful. It sounds like your View might be inheriting the wrong type of model.

Comment: Added some code. The view is using the right type for the model.  As Charlino identifies this probably isn't a bug, but a consequence.  The problem is this consequence breaks automation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because when you use something like `@Html.HiddenFor( m => m.Id )` the html helpers look in various places to populate the input's value, and the values in the route is one of those places.

So you could either change your route so that it's something like `template/customize/{TemplateId}` and then have your action method reflect this, e.g. `public ActionResult Customize(int templateId)`.

OR you could change your viewmodel (or create a custom view model) that has a `CustomizationId` property rather than just `Id`.

And no, it's not a bug... it's more of a feature that can have unforeseen consequences. But once you're aware of it, it works like a treat.

Comment: I realize that I'm probably bending the rules and breaking a few of them as well.  Definitely feeling the pain of that, but I still feel like m.Id should always be the Model.Id not the Route.Id unless model doesn't exist in the context.

Comment: You lead me to an acceptable solution so I'm marking your answer.  Following up with an edit containing what I did.

Comment: Just want to clarify, that any of your other solutions would have worked as well (and the route would have been more elegant). I just didn't want to create a new route in my route table.

Comment: Why why why does it get a value from a route rather than element on a form? Do you happen to know where I can read more about this? Thank you

Comment: I buy this as a feature if you are using a dynamic typed model, but that's not the case. You won't even be able to add a hidden to another route parameter because the HiddenFor will expect an expression wich returns a memberexpression pointing to a property of the model type.
As an example, you won't be able to do Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.Controller)

Comment: I feel like this is a bug.  If I'm using a strongly typed view I would expect model => model.Id to look in exactly one place for the Id that being the view model.

Answer (score 8):

You can always choose not to use the HTML Helper in this case and use plain HTML instead:

> `<input name="Id" id="Id" type="hidden" value="@Model.Id"/>`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent route values from overriding the model's corresponding properties, call `ModelState.Clear()` in your controller action. Be careful to call this method *after* using/reading the model state.

```
public ActionResult Customize( int id )
{
    var template = Persistence.Data.RetrieveObject<Template>( id );
    var model = new Customization();

    ViewBag.Template = template;

    this.ViewData.ModelState.Clear(); // add that after you consume the ModelState
    return ( View( model ) );
}
```

On my side, the hidden input gets the model's value instead of the route value.