# Model Key and Foreign Key parametres are null in controller after POST action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have the following hidden fields inside my View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cat.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cat.OwnerId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cat.BirthDate        
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cat.Weight)
```

Id is a Key and OwnerId is a ForeignKey. When I try to edit that model, all values are displayed correctly but the problem is when I try to POST those values back. Id and OwnerId are always 0. I have a lot of other values inside my view like dropdown lists, text boxes etc, all those values are posted correctly. The problem is only with Id and OwnerId.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditCatDetailsViewModel model)
{
Debug.WriteLine("Cat Id: " + model.cat.Id); //displays 0
}
```

I checked source of web site and I see Id and OwnerId have correct values (values aren't 0). My question is why are those values not sent like all other values? Why are they received in controller as 0?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

Cat Edit View:

```
@model Pro.Web.Models.EditCatDetailsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit Cat Details</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Cat</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cat.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cat.OwnerId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cat.BirthDate        
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cat.Weight)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cat.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cat.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cat.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cat.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.cat.Description, new { @style="width:400px; height:600px" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cat.Description)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cat.NumberOfKittens)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cat.NumberOfKittens)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cat.NumberOfKittens)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Details", "Details")
</div>
```

Comment: I assume they are placed inside the `<form>` element that you are posting?

Comment: Yes. All those hidden fields are posted inside a form and displayed correctly. Weird thing is that when model is received in controller, first two fields are 0 and other fields have their normal values.

Comment: hmmm, and there's no other input element with `name="cat.Id"` present after the hidden input?

Comment: No, I checked that. I also tried to put EditorFor but thos elements but they were still not posted.

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin How do you check that they are not posted? 'Fiddler' OR 'Request.Params' OR ...?

Comment: Hmmm indeed odd. The only other thing I can think of at the moment is if the properties maybe have the `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` attribute? Something else you could check: are they posted as 0? What does `HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery` look like?

Comment: @webdeveloper - there is an exception while saving to a database and I see a state of the model inside Locals window. I see that all values are set, except Id and OwnerId. `Debug.WriteLine("Cat Id: " + model.cat.Id);` also displays 0 in Console.

Comment: @MajorByte - Id has this attribute: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Comment: @ZdravkoVajudin `WriteLine` is too late for checking. Do you have routes with `Id` and `OwnerId`? It's importsnt to know are this values posted correctly. Set breakpoint and check `Request` data.

Comment: could you update your answer with your viewmodel?

Comment: I've set a breakpoint and those values are the only ones that are 0. @MajorByte - I updated my question.

Comment: I wanted to know your ViewModel, not your view. Also, when you've hit the breakpoint can you check the value of `HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery` and post it here as a comment, as @webdeveloper and I asked before?

Comment: @MajorByte - `HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery` gives the following result: `/Cats/Edit/1`. The Id of the edited cat is indeed 1.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I managed to do it like this. I put additional variable inside my EditCatDetailsViewModel which represents a cat id.

This is simplified look of that model now:

```
public class EditCatDetailsViewModel
{
    public Cat cat { get; set; }
    public int catId { get; set; }

}
```

Inside my GET Edit method I've set that Id from Id in Cat model:

```
// GET: /Cats/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Cat cat = _catRepository.Find(id);

        if (cat == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        EditCatDetailsViewModel model = new EditCatDetailsViewModel();
        model.cat = cat;
        model.catId = cat.Id;

        return View(model);
    }
```

And in my View I added additional hidden element:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.catId)
```

Now I can access that Id in POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditCatDetailsViewModel model)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Cat Id: " + model.catId); //displays correct Id for Cat!!!
    model.cat.Id = model.catId;
}
```

Now it all works and I can save changes to my DB. I am still interested why those values were not posted the first time.

Comment: It's hard to help remotely, I think it could be conflict. Something like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358913/asp-net-mvc-modelbinder-bug-binding-request-variable-id-to-models-property OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315926/asp-net-mvc-3-model-id-using-route-id-value

Answer (score -1):

Hi Its seems that hidden field generated via razor does not updates their values on posting them back again. So please try to make your hidden fields via html syntex not with razor like this:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="@Model.model.cat.Id" />
    <input type="hidden" id="" name="" value="@Model.model.cat.OwnerId" />
```

Check your page source and copy the value of  name attribute of these hidden fields from there and assign them here and now check I hope you will get those values also in your action method.

Comment: How would this be different from the ones generated with the `HiddenFor`?

Comment: The hidden fields generated via Razor does not update themselves if you change their values and submit the form again. I had the same problem in my current project and when I converted the hidden fields from  Razor to HTML I got their updated values at the time form submission.

Comment: @JitenderMuwal, you probably had another issue, because what you propose is exactly what `Html.HiddenFor()` does.

Comment: Nice solution, without `name` and `id` model binder will never understand for which these properties are. Also browser could ignore such useful properties.